# Is the JMS QueueSender thread safe?

Tags: java, queue, jms, thread-safety

I want to use a QueueSender in a multi-threaded environment.

Is `QueueSender.send()` thread safe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, a `MessageProducer`/`QueueSender` is not thread safe.

Or more specifically: The [`Session`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/jms/Session.html) is not thread safe. The JavaDoc for `Session` explicitly mentions this in its first sentence:

> A Session object is a single-threaded context for producing and consuming messages.

And since a `MessageProducer`/`QueueSender` is bound to a `Session` you must not use it from more than one thread at the same time. In fact you must not use it from two different threads at different times either!

Comment: You can use it from multiple threads if you synchronize usage. The JMS specification says :'There are no restrictions on the number of threads that can use a Session object or those it creates. The restriction
is that the resources of a Session should not be used concurrently by multiple threads'

Answer (score 13):

Following screenshot is from JMS2 specs

[image]

As you can see Session Object does not support usage by concurrent threads. Session is not a thread safe Object. Same gos for all Objects created from that Session instance like `Messages,Producers,Consumers`. So these objects must not be shared by two threads and this is something client should take care of instead of JMS providers.