# What does JMS Session single-threadedness mean?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, tibco-ems

What is the exact nature of the thread-unsafety of a JMS Session and its associated constructs (Message, Consumer, Producer, etc)?  Is it just that access to them must be serialized, or is it that access is restricted to the creating thread only?

Or is it a hybrid case where creation can be distinguished from use, i.e. one thread can create them only and then another thread can be the only one to use them?  This last possibility would seem to contradict the statement in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266481/191671) which says "In fact you must not use it from two different threads at different times either!"

But consider the ["Server Side" example code](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html#HowshouldIimplementrequestresponsewithJMS-ServerSide) from the ActiveMQ documentation.

The Server class has data members named session (of type Session) and replyProducer (of type MessageProducer) which are

- created in one thread: whichever one invokes the Server() constructor and thereby invokes the setupMessageQueueConsumer() method with the actual creation calls; and
- used in another thread: whichever one invokes the onMessage() asynchronous callback.

(In fact, the session member is *used* in both threads too: in one to create the replyProducer member, and in the other to create a message.)

Is this official example code working by accident or by design? Is it really possible to create such objects in one thread and then arrange for another thread to use them?

(Note: in other messaging infrastructures, such as Solace, it's possible to specify the thread on which callbacks occur, which could be exploited to get around this "thread affinity of objects" restriction, but no such API call is defined in JMS, as far as I know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer appears to be a footnote to section 4.4. "Session" on p.60 in the [JMS 1.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7195-jms-1.1-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).

> There are no restrictions on the number of threads that can use a Session object or those it creates. The restriction is that the resources of a Session should not be used concurrently by multiple threads. It is up to the user to insure that this concurrency restriction is met. The simplest way to do this is to use one thread. In the case of asynchronous delivery, use one thread for setup in stopped mode and then start asynchronous delivery. In more complex cases the user must provide explicit synchronization.

Whether a particular implementation abides by this is another matter, of course.   In the case of the ActiveMQ example, the code is conforming because all inbound message handling is through a single asynchronous callback.

Answer (score 0):

JMS specification says a session object should not be used across threads except when calling `Session.Close()` method. Technically speaking if access to Session object or it's children (producer, consumer etc) is serialized then Session or it's child objects can be accessed across threads. Having said that, since JMS is an API specification, it's implementation differs from vendor to vendor. Some vendors might strictly enforce the thread affinity while some may not. So it's always better to stick to JMS specification and write code accordingly.

Comment: So, is the example code from the ActiveMQ documentation working by accident or by design?  In other words, is it compliant with the JMS specification or is it not?

Comment: In my opinion it's not following spec.